# Word to express a building's potential to be guarded against a forced exit

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a word that expresses the idea of a prison being difficult to escape because of its physical construction, in a similar way that 'fortified' means a structure is difficult to attack from outside because of its physical construction.

The context of this is something like, "The school building is more heavily guarded/fortified/etc. than the prison," but without the sense that there are actually people there guarding it or that existing architectural measures (like barricades, fence gates, security balcony with bulletproof shields at intervals, etc) are in active use. Rather, it is just constructed in a way that would make it easy to guard, or has such features.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps *[impregnable](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/impregnable)*

> unable to be broken into or taken by force: *an impregnable castle*

While this suggests being attacked from without, the example you give, a school building, is usually concerned with intruders rather than inmates.

You also could consider *[inescapable](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inescapable)*

> incapable of being escaped or avoided

This is probably more often used figuratively, referring to ideas or conclusions, but may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You might say *locked down* or *impenetrable*, though I think *fortified* works for getting out as well as getting in.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives are ***fortressed***

from the verb form of [***fortress***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fortress?s=ts)

> to protect with or as if with a fortress

and ***bulwarked***

again from the verb form of [***bulwark***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bulwark?s=t)

> to fortify or protect with a bulwark; secure by or as if by a fortification.

Answer (score 1):

> A [***secured***](http://gog.is/define+secured) or [***invulnerable***](http://gog.is/define+invulnerable) structure would suggest an internally fortified structure to me.